# Bug on amcharts shows 100.00% in every column when i use [[percents]]

Tags: c#, javascript, amcharts

I have this strange bug in my code.
When I use amcharts and I'm trying to show the percentage on each column, every column is 100.00 percent.

```
AmCharts.ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'Analytics/GetDivergenceByApp?appid=46',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json;',
        //data: JSON.stringify({ id: checkId }),
        success: function run(dataset) {
            // RADAR CHART
            chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
            chart.dataProvider = dataset;
            chart.categoryField = "col";
            chart.startDuration = 1;
            chart.sequencedAnimation = false;


            var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
            categoryAxis.gridPosition = "start";

            // VALUE AXIS
            var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
            valueAxis.axisAlpha = 0.15;
            valueAxis.minimum = 0;
            valueAxis.dashLength = 3;
            valueAxis.stackType = "regular";
            chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);



            // GRAPH
            var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
            graph.type = "column";
            graph.labelText = "[[percents]]%";
            graph.valueField = "value";
            graph.title = "All Pushes";
            graph.fillAlphas = 0.6;
            graph.balloonText = "[[value]] os type installations";
            chart.addGraph(graph);

            // WRITE
            chart.write("chartdiv2");
        }
    });
});
```

I'm using C# with MVC4 to get the data and I should note it appears fine on the chart.
How do I fix that to show the real percentage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't work, [[percents]] display the percentage of the graph of one series, so it makes sense only if you have more than one graph. In your case you should calculate the percent values manually, add them to your data, with some custom field name like "percentsCalculated" and then display this value in a label: [[percentsCalculated]]

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm. :)